# Changed from DHCP to static but cannot resolve name

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I just installed a Debian 9.6 amd64 on a VirtualBox with NAT. I had to change the network settings from DHCP to static and with a netmask of /30 because it is in my assignment. So I followed a few articles and changed my /etc/network/interface for it to be like this:

```
allow-hotplug enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
     address 10.0.0.41
     netmask 255.255.255.252 // Because I have to a set a netmask of /30
     gateway 10.0.0.0
     broadcast 10.0.0.43
     gateway 10.0.0.1
     dns-nameserver 10.0.0.1 8.8.8.8
     dns-domain acme.com
     dns-search acme.com
```

But after restarting the network service I keep getting temporary failure in name resolution and I can't fetch for anything to install.

EDIT1: I reset everything to see my original IP's and interfaces when still on DHCP, and the result of `ip a` is like this:

```
1: lo:
   inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: enp0s3:
   inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global enp0s3
```

Comment: You also have to define name/dns servers.

Comment: @MrZach Hey, I added the following to the file:
dns-nameserver 192.168.3.254
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
But still not working

Comment: Did you try a traceroute to 8.8.8.8?

Comment: @MrZach It says network is unreachable.
I edited my post with the full information i have now.

Comment: multiple gateway entries there, are you intended to do so?

Comment: @SimonMC.Cheng Ah, no I'm not, I just copied what I found in a certain article so I'm not sure what should I delete exactly or keep.

Comment: I think your first step is to change back to DHCP and run ifconfig to check what is the valid IP configuration for your VM, then back to setup static configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to use a netmask of 255.255.255.252 (a /30) there are only two valid IP addresses in the subnet. One of them will be assigned to your server (10.0.0.41) and the other will have to be a router, i.e. your default gateway. Thus, you should put in the following configuration:

```
gateway 10.0.0.42
```

That being said, you are running this on Virtualbox. Virtualbox normally uses internal /24 networks. Why do you think you *must* use a /30?

Since you're using NAT on your VirtualBox machine, the VM connects to an internal network (see previous comment) and it is VirtualBox who is the DHCP server. Perhaps your physical machine requires a static IP address from your network administrator, but on your local machine on your local VirtualBox networks, you can do whatever you want.

By the sound of it you don't really understand networking that well (no offense). Perhaps more information on your setup and the requirements will allow us to help you better.

**Edit:**

Since you insist on using a /30 network, you should create one in VirtualBox. Otherwise VirtualBox wil assume a /24 network and it will provide a default gateway with an IP address that is inaccessible to your virtual machine. For the details, check the [documentation on virtual networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat_service).

```
VBoxManage natnetwork add --netname exercise1 --network "10.0.0.40/30" --enable
VBoxManage natnetwork start --netname exercise1
```

To add port forwarding for services, use a command such as:

```
VBoxManage natnetwork modify --netname exercise1 \
    --port-forward-4 "ssh:tcp:[]:2222:[10.0.0.42]:22"
```

Finally, you must modify the settings of your virtual machine and attach it to this newly created network called "exercise1". Inside the VM you must update your interface configuration and */etc/resolv.conf*.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I'm sorry for the late, but my original setup information is this:
When running `ip a`
1: lo:
inet 127.0.0.1/8
2: enp0s3: 
inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global enp0s3

And yes, I am very new to networking, no offense taken. I'm glad you took the time to reply to me in detail. I will try using what you suggested.

Comment: Edited my reply. : )

Comment: Now you state the interface has a prefix length of 24 while in the question, it had to be 30. What changed?

Comment: Ah, no. I started over as Simon suggested in the comment and ran `ip a` to see my original information. I still have to use a netmask of /30 since I have to run an nginx server after this and be able to access it from outside Virtualbox.

Comment: Again, your requirement of using a /30 does not make sense to me. If you want to change the internal Virtualbox network from a /24 to a /30 you need to modify the settings on Virtualbox as well.

Comment: I'm not completely sure why I must use it as well, but it is my assignment so I'm just doing it. Could you point me to which settings do I need to change on Virtualbox? I realize this isn't the place for tutorials but if you could do that, it would be great.

Comment: I will look into it. In the meantime, can you update your question with (1) the IP settings you listed in the comment earlier, and (2) the assignment you just referred to. That way we can better understand the requirements and adjust our answer to that.